# Am I using the wrong CMD command?

Tags: dockerfile

Sorry I can speak a little English and thank you for clicking this question.

I made docker images, it's base is centos and installed apache-tomcat, and jdk12

It's name and tag are sadb0101/cja:0.1

I wrote Dockerfile based on the image I made earlier to set some environment variables and export ports.

but it didn't work

```
FROM sadb0101/cja:0.1

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk-12.0.2
ENV CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.46
ENV CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/jsp-api.jar:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/servlet-api.jar
ENV PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin

EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.46/bin
CMD ./startup.sh
```

```sh
docker build -t sadb0101/cja:0.2 .
docker run -d -p 8888:8080 sadb0101/cja:0.2
```

When I enter shell command written above, I want my server to enter 8888 port and the tomcat main screen will appear.

help me plz  ㅠ.ㅠ

I push sadb0101/cja:0.1 images at docker hub

Comment: sadb0101/cja:0.1 what is this ? is this your old image ?

Comment: Which of the command fails `docker build` , or `docker run`, or none? Execute `docker ps -a | grep 'sadb0101/cja'` to see the status of the container (and also it's name).
Use `docker logs {containers_name}` command to see the output of the startup.sh.

Comment: 0.1 image has centos,tomcat,jdk installed
no error docker run and build but didn't work ./startup.sh